# How to switch from Street view to ROADMAP using google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is my setting: I have a table in one part of my screen with location information; and the second part of the screen displays google map of the of the location selected in the first part of the screen.  This works find, i.e. when the user click on any item in the table the second screen pans to the new location.

In the 2nd screen, the Street View option is enable allowing the user to use it.

Here is my problem.  When the user choose Street View and then click on the table, I would like to switch back to ROADMAP type (from Street View) and then pan to the new location.

I try to use MyMapHandler.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) but this does not switch from Street View to ROADMAP.

Is there such a command in google API to do this?

Thank-you all in advance for helping.
PS: I don't want to pan while in Street View mode - because some locations does not have the view, etc...

Answer (score 1):

you must set the visible-property of the streetView to false:

```
MyMapHandler.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle. Thanks a million!  That is exactly what I need. It works like a charm!